# Firefox 4 upgrade broke R-Kiosk... Easy work around?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I need to use a Firefox addon called [R-Kiosk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/Firefox/addon/r-kiosk/).  I upgraded to Firefox 4 from Firefox 3, and now R-Kiosk is not working.  I don't see a version of r-kiosk that says it supports ff4...

Does anyone have any ideas as to the easiest way I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the addon is still compatible, and it's just marked as incompatible because the developer hasn't updated it yet. If this is the case, you can disable compatibility checking by going to `about:config` and changing the preference `extensions.checkCompatibility.4.0` to `false`.

If it actually *is* incompatible (i.e. if you disable compatibility checking and it still doesn't work), then you'll need to wait for the developer to update their code, or open up the extension's XPI file (it's just a zip file with a `.xpi` name) and modify it yourself. Once you understand [the basics of Firefox addon development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772/how-do-i-write-a-firefox-addon), look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Updating_extensions_for_Firefox_4 to get an idea of what changes you'll need to make.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Add on compatibility reporter Firefox add on](http://reviewsmyfavourite.blogspot.com/2010/07/firefox-add-on-compatilbility-reporter.html)

After installing add on compatibility reporter Firefox stops checking compatibility. You can continue and install R-kiosk firefox add on. There are chances for misbehaviour. If you find any uninstall the add on.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to 3.6 and wait for compatibility? That seems like the easiest approach to me.